# asp.net identity 2 require particular claim to log in

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

In MVC5 asp.net - Is there a way to allow user login only if the user has a particular claim in the user database? I'd like to assign a "CanLogin" claim to users in my user database that are allowed to log in at any given time. By removing the "CanLogin" claim, I could effectively lock the users out of the system until further notice.

This would have to work for a first time login as well as cookie login at a later stage if the user has checked "remember my login".

Answer (score 0):

Using authentication filter, you can check the identity.claims property to validate whatever claims are present in the context.
The claims must be added during the login process
Then you can check whether a particular user is enabled or not.

However, if the user database is self maintained, you can just set a disabled flag and then reject the login request, instead of returning such a claim.

The claims are used for Authorization to a particular functionality rather than Authentication to an app. A valid user will have certain claims which can tell what all the user is permitted to do.

Comment: I'm looking for ways to ensure your right to login which would mean hooking into the authentication process I guess. While you're of course right that claims are for authorization rather than authentication, in this case I'm looking for a way to do exactly that, authorize the login. But I get your point, in a way I might be stretching too far using claims for this purpose. Never the less, that's what the original question is about. I realize also that perhaps the answer to the question is that it's wrong to go in this direction. And that I should add a disabled flag to my database.